# Flask Socket IO Callback Message in Server Command Prompt

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I've looked everywhere but am having trouble finding an explanation for this and I'm not sure if I am just overlooking something or it just doesn't function the way I'm expecting it to.

There is a "messageReceived" callback being passed with the response after receiving "my event" from the client:

```
def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)
```

However, I never see the "messageReceived" function execute on the server?  I'm expecting to see 'message was received!!!' somewhere in the command prompt for the server but I do not.  Is there something that needs to be sent back from the client in order to execute the callback or should it happen automatically?    Everything else is functioning as you would expect.

Here is the client-side javascript:

```
socket.on('my response', function( msg ) {
    console.log( msg )
    if( typeof msg.user_name !=='undefined') {
        $('h3').remove()
        $('div.message_holder').append('<div><b style="color: #000">'+ msg.user_name +'</b> '+ msg.message +'</div>')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the callback is **not** automated from the client side.  Added this to the client-side javascript and everything works now as expected:

```
socket.on('my response', function( msg, callback ) {
    console.log( msg )
    if( typeof msg.user_name !=='undefined') {
        $('h3').remove()
        $('div.message_holder').append('<div><b style="color: #000">'+ msg.user_name +'</b> '+ msg.message +'</div>')
    }
    callback();
})
```

[Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-on-eventName-callback) was also helpful.